# How to create fast or slow camera flash blink signals in Android?

Tags: android, camera

I have service that make flash blink signals:

```
    public class FlashBlinkService extends Service 
    {
        private static Camera cam = null;
        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();
            startFlashBlink();      
        }

        //for simulating flash blink
        Runnable flashBlinkRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {   
                cam = Camera.open();
                Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
                //--->
                handler.post(flashBlinkRunnable);
            }       
        };

        //start flash blink light
        public void startFlashBlink()
        {
            flashBlinkRunnable.run();
        }

        //stop flash blink light
        public void stopFlashBlink()
        {
            handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
            stopCamera(cam);
        }

        //stop camera
        private void stopCamera(Camera cam)
        {
            if (cam != null)
            {
                cam.stopPreview();
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            super.onDestroy();
            handler.removeCallbacks(flashBlinkRunnable);
            stopCamera(cam);
        }
    }
```

This is the 'fastest' flash blink solution right now for me. Which is the best way to make faster or slower flash blink signals? There is a lots of applications in the market (like some flashlights) that provide this option. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've accomplished this in the following way. The frequency of the strobe (flash blinking) is regulated by the *sleepMS* variable in the *Thread.sleep()* function. For example if you want 10 flashes at 10 Hz you would set

```
sleepMS=(1/10)*50;
flashCount=10;
```

Or more general:

```
sleepMS=(1/Hz)*1000/2
```

Not sure is the best way to accomplish this but it works.

```
Camera cam;
Parameters params;

private void main(){
    cam = Camera.open();
    params = cam.getParameters();
    cam.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
    cam.startPreview();

    for (int i = 0; i < flashCount; i++) {
        flipFlash();
        Thread.sleep(sleepMS);
        flipFlash();
        Thread.sleep(sleepMS);
    }
    cam.stopPreview();
    cam.release();
}

private void flipFlash(){
    if (isLighOn) {
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(params);
        isLighOn = false;
    } else{
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(params);
        isLighOn = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the response is right can you please accept it as "Correct Answer" ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread and after each turnOn/turnOff sleep the thread as long as you want the pause to be